# QR код генерится с неправильной кодировкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, qr, qrcode

Проблема в генерации qr кода. Есть стандарты сбербанка по тому, как должна выглядеть строка и какая кодировка должна использоваться(windows-1251).
https://www.sberbank.ru/common/img/uploaded/files/shtrih-kod-standart.pdf

Так вот, я использую django-qr-code или что-то такое, qr код генерится, и сканируется сбер-онлайном, но некоторые поля, расшифровываются как-то так - РЈР¤Рљ РїРѕ РўРѕРјСЃРєРѕР№ РѕР±Р»Р°СЃС‚Рё

Подозреваю, что я неправильно использую методы encode/decode. Python 3.5 используется.

Немного кода прикладываю:

view.py

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    listener = self.get_listener()

    form = l_f.InvoiceForm(request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
        customer = listener.customer.get_fio_dict()
        qr_text = "ST00011|Name=УФК по Томской области (ТГПУ л/с 0000Ы0000)|" \
                  "PersonalAcc=0000000000|" \
                  "BankName=Отделение Томск|" \
                  "BIC=00000000|" \
                  "CorrespAcc=0|" \
                  "PayeeINN=000000000|" \
                  "Category=Образовательные услуги" \
                  "LastName="+customer['surname']+"|" \
                  "FirstName="+customer['name']+"|" \
                  "MiddleName="+customer['father_name']+"|" \
                  "Contract="+listener.order_number+"|" \
                  "PayerAddress=ул. Пупкина 22|" \
                  "Sum=" + str(int(form.cleaned_data['invoice_sum']) * 100)


        print(qr_text.encode().decode('windows-1251'))
        context = {
            'listener': listener,
            'title': 'Квитанция на оплату',
            'month': form.cleaned_data['month'],
            'invoice_sum': form.cleaned_data['invoice_sum'],
            'qr_text': qr_text.encode().decode('windows-1251')
            # 'bank_sum': form.cleaned_data['bank_sum']

        }
    else:
        context = {}

    return render(request, 'docs/templates_of_views/kvitancia.html', context)
```

Comment: "РЈР¤Рљ РїРѕ РўРѕРјСЃРєРѕР№ РѕР±Р»Р°СЃС‚Рё" - это текст, закодированный в UTF-8 и прочитанный как win-1251

Comment: Если в `encode` или `decode` не передать название кодировки, то будет использована utf-8. Соответственно `qr_text.encode().decode('windows-1251')` кодирует строку **в utf-8** и сразу же декодирует **из cp1251**. Какой вообще смысл у вызова `endode` и `decode` подряд?

Comment: Получается, если вызвать encode('cp1251'), то текст просто закодиркется в этом формате и потом с помощью этого формата должен будет нормально декодироваться в читабельный текст?... Не понимаю, почему до меня это сразу не дошло) Всем спасибо большое)